# Edit an array from another with different length C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I need help with this code which doesn't work...

I want to change items from Array1, itemps position depending on Array2 items, 
where Array1 = Array0 and Array0 values are always changing.

Here is what I tried:

```
float[] Array0 = {1.524,2.345,3.12,4.55,5.345};
float[] Array1 = Array0;
int[] Array2 = {2,1,3};

foreach (int item in Array2)
    if(item!=0)
        Array1[item]=0;
```

Output :

```
Array1 = {1.524,0,0,0,5.345}
```

Do you have any solution ?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Arrays are reference types. So when you do `float[] Array1 = Array2` you get a pointer to the same array in memory. So there is just 1 array with 2 pointers to it. Looks like you want `Array1` to be a copy of `Array0`. Try `float[] Array1 = Array0.ToArray();`

Comment: @Knoop I'd prefer `float[] Array1 = (float[])Array0.Clone();` myself.

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in comments, you need to make a copy of `array0` into `array1` with `Clone()`:

```
var array0 = new []{ 1.524, 2.345, 3.12, 4.55, 5.345 };
var array1 = (double[])array0.Clone();
int[] array2 = { 2, 1, 3 };

//change array0
array0[2] += 5;
array0[3] += 5;
array0[4] += 5;

foreach (var idx in array2.Where(idx => Math.Abs(array0[idx] - array1[idx]) > 1e-6))
    array1[idx] = 0;

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", array1));
```

Result:

```
1.524 2.345 0 0 5.345
```